# Why does $\int \frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2}dx = - \ln|1-e^x|+C$?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I worked through $\int \frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2}dx$ using u-substitution, but my answer, $(1-e^x)^{-1}+C$ is incorrect. It should be $- \ln|1-e^x|+C$

> $$\int \frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2}dx$$

Let $u = 1 - e^x$

Then $du = -e^x$ and $dx = \frac{-du}{e^x}$

So $\int \frac{e^x}{u^2} \frac{-1}{e^x}du = -\int \frac{1}{u^2}du = -\int u^{-2}du$

$$-\int u^{-2} du$$

$$=-(\frac{u^{-1}}{-1})+C$$

$$=u^{-1}+C$$

$$=(1-e^x)^{-1}+C$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry everyone. I had plugged $\int \frac{e^x}{1-e^x}dx$ instead of $\int \frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2}dx$ into SymboLab.com's calculator. That's why I was confused.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is the correct one, as you can confirm by differentiating both. In general you can always confirm whether you got the right primitive by differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

The result is false: in fact,

$$\int\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2}dx=\frac1{1-e^x} +C$$

This is: what you did is completely correct. There is not $\;\ln\;$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is perfectly fine and agrees with what [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Ex%2F%281-e%5Ex%29%5E2) returns. You should give a source as the source seems to be wrong in its given answer.